# How to glue multiple tables together in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to analyse Google analytics data for the past 30 days in BigQuery.

I have tables for each day, saved in the format *ga_sessions_YYYYMMDD*

I'm trying to 'glue' them together, instead of using JOIN ON some column, I would like to simply add more rows to the data.

The tables have identical schema.

Query Edit:

```
SELECT fullVisitorId,visitID,visitNumber,totals.timeOnSite,totals.pageviews,totals.sessionQualityDim,device.deviceCategory,
FROM '12345678.ga_sessions_*' WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20171031' AND '20171001'
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6
ORDER BY totals.timeOnSite DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This solution is for Standard SQL.**

What you need is either `UNION ALL` or `WILDCARD` in `FROM` clause as described in https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables.

If you want to query specific dates, you can use `_TABLE_SUFFIX` pseudo-column, similarly to this query:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `ga_sessions_*`
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20171031' AND '20171001'
```

Comment: After adding my ID before ga_sessions such as 12412141.ga_sessions_* , I get the error:
Query Failed
Error: Encountered " "FROM" "FROM "" at line 2, column 1. Was expecting: <EOF>. P.S. I added my Query in the question

Comment: This could be due the fact that I might be on legacy SQL while this is standard SQL syntax. I'm also using https://bigquery.cloud.google.com to run my commands

Comment: I had to click -> Show Options -> uncheck Legacy SQL

Comment: I've updated my answer to highlight that this solution is only for Standard SQL.